# Is it possible to keep wallet connection between different react apps

Tags: reactjs, metamask, micro-frontend

Is it possible to keep wallet connection between different React apps hosted on same domain? I'd like to host few different React apps, but I'd like to keep the connection instead of prompting the modal to connect your wallet again.

Comment: That doesn't seem very secure.

Comment: Can you add some code? Maybe your attempt or some psuedo?